# Signature calculation mismatch with CloudFormation + Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-route53

I have a problem whentrying to manage my Route53 zoens with CloudFormation.

The error I have is:

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you
>   provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult
>   the service documentation for details.

I trigger CloudFormation from console, not through API/CLI. I'm logged on my IAM user with full account access.

The error occurs for any sub-stack that tries to add record set to hosted zone, the zone itself is created successfully with another stack (together with some record sets).

This is an example record set resource that fails (if I remove this one it fails on different one and if it also happens in different stacks as well):

```
Mx:
    Type: "AWS::Route53::RecordSet"
    Properties:
        HostedZoneId: !Ref "HostedZoneId"
        Name: !Sub "mailer.${DomainName}."
        Type: "MX"
        ResourceRecords:
            - "10 mx.sendgrid.net."
        TTL: 3600
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems AWS CF had some hiccup, or they were just dpeloying some updates. Just re-tried after few hours and it works (not quite, I have other problems, but still).